# IIS resources DebugDiag Logs - safe to delete?

Tags: iis, logging

Is it safe to delete the logs \Program Files\IIS Resources\DebugDiag\ in the Logs and perflogs folders?

We've got a dev server with a badly partitioned drive and could use the space.

Comment: I'd highly recommend changing the names of the folders and seeing if anything goes wrong. If it does, just change them back, else, delete them! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, the answer seems to be:  Yes, it's safe to delete them!

http://help.wugnet.com/windows2/DebugDiag-Log-Files-Deleted-ftopict493502.html
http://forums.techarena.in/window-2000-help/899911.htm